# Board game Java - Board GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have to do a Java project for school and I decided to make a board game: Stratego. But I've been stuck for a while now on the GUI of the actual board. 
My intention is to make a frame with a background image of the board and on top of that(as in an upper layer) a grid where I would be able to assign coordinates for each square of the grid. When a piece is created, it can be assigned a square by the player, so that square has to be able to show an image of a piece.

And that is where I've been stuck for weeks! I can't seem to find how to make a frame with several layers. Do you know a simpler implementation?
 I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

EDIT:I should have probably put what I've already done:

```
public class FenetreJeu extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static  int TILE_OFFSET= 60;//Constant for the coordinates

public FenetreJeu() {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(700,700);
    Panel background= new Panel();
    background.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(background);
    background.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10,1,1));

}

private void createAndAddPiece(int couleur, int rang, int x, int y) {
    Image img = this.getImagePion(couleur, rang);
    switch(rang){
        case Pion.RANG_MARECHAL:
            Marechal marechal = new Marechal();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_GENERAL:
            General general = new General();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_COLONEL:
            Colonel colonel = new Colonel();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_COMMANDANT:
            Commandant commandant = new Commandant();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_CAPITAINE:
            Capitaine capitaine = new Capitaine();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_LIEUTENANT:
            Lieutenant lieutenant = new Lieutenant();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_SERGENT:
            Sergent sergent = new Sergent();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_DEMINEUR:
            Demineur demineur = new Demineur();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_ECLAIREUR:
            Eclaireur eclaireur = new Eclaireur();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_ESPION:
            Espion espion = new Espion();
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_DRAPEAU:
            Drapeau drapeau = new Drapeau(Pion.RANG_DRAPEAU,Pion.STATIQUE);
            break;
        case Pion.RANG_BOMBE:
            Bombe bombe = new Bombe(Pion.RANG_BOMBE,Pion.STATIQUE);
            break;
    }

}


private Image getImagePion(int couleur, int rang) {//Method to get the image of the piece

    String filename = "";

    filename += ( couleur == Pion.COLOR_RED ? "/Ressources/PionsRouges/" : "/Ressources/PionsBleus/");
    switch (rang) {
        case pions.Pion.RANG_MARECHAL:
            filename += "9";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_GENERAL:
            filename += "8";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_COLONEL:
            filename += "7";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_COMMANDANT:
            filename += "6";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_CAPITAINE:
            filename += "5";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_LIEUTENANT:
            filename += "4";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_SERGENT:
            filename += "3";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_DEMINEUR:
            filename += "2";
        case pions.Pion.RANG_ECLAIREUR:
            filename += "1";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_ESPION:
            filename += "10";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_DRAPEAU:
            filename += "0";
            break;
        case pions.Pion.RANG_BOMBE:
            filename += "-1";
            break;
    }
    filename += ".gif";

    URL urlPieceImg = getClass().getResource(filename);
    return (new ImageIcon(urlPieceImg).getImage());
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the Java docs for the [usage of JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)?

Comment: It might also help to tell us (and tag the question with) the Java GUI toolkit you are using, such as Swing, SWT, etc.

Comment: If anything you should use the background image on the Frame, create JPanels ontop of the background to make the game board squares, get the icons you want to represent the pieces, set them accordingly to the beginning of the game, use mouse of keyboard commands to select and move specific pieces and program what the pieces are capable of for movement and use.

Comment: When I've made a game like this, I draw the background image on a JPanel.  The pieces are images that I draw on the JPanel.  The JPanel is added to the JFrame.  Take a look at my [2048 Game in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516) to see how I drew a game board.

Comment: I've edited the question, with the code that I've already written. FYI "rang" is the rank of the piece. I made constants of the ranks in a super class.